# Fetch Nested Data with getstaticprops and getstaticpaths in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, next.js

```json
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "First Post",
        "postcontent": "What is Lorem Ipsum?\r\nLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/card_2qRdGJ9.png",
        "slug": "first-post",
        "keywords": [
            "stevie",
            "clowns",
            "water",
            "ray"
        ],
        "form_field_options": [
            {
                "form_field": 1,
                "description": "Author description 1",
                "form_image": 1,
                "author_name": "Author Name Two",
                "id": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The [slug].js

```js
import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'

function slug({post}) {
    return (
        <div>
           <Head>
            <title>{post.title}</title>
            </Head>

            <Image src={post.image} alt={'say it'} width={500} height={500} />

            <div>{post.title}</div>
            <div>{post.form_field_options.description ? post.form_field_options.description: ""}</div>
            
            

            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.postcontent }}></div>
        </div>
        
    )

    
}


export default slug


export const getStaticPaths = async () => {

    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/lasttwo/');
    const posts = await res.json();

    const paths = posts.map (post => ({
        params: {slug: `${post.slug}`}
        
    }));
    return{
        paths,
        fallback:false,
    }
}



export async function getStaticProps({params}) {
    
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/lasttwo/');
    const posts = await res.json();
    
    const post = posts.filter(post => post.slug.includes(params.slug));
    

    return {
        props: {
            post: post[0],
          
        }
    }

    
}
```

The index.js

```js
import BlogHome from '../../components/BlogHome/BlogHome'



export default function home({ posts }) {
  return (
    
      <BlogHome posts={posts}/>
    
  )
}

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/lasttwo/');
  const posts = await res.json();
  
  return {
      props: {
          posts,
      }
  }

  
}
```

The component file:

```js
import React from 'react'

import Link from 'next/link'
import { useState } from 'react'
import Image from 'next/image'



function BlogHome({ posts }) {
    

    const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

    const filteredPosts = posts.filter(
        post =>
        post.title.toLowerCase(). includes(keyword) || post.keywords.includes(keyword)
    )

    const onInputchange  = (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        setKeyword(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <input placeholder="search for keywords..." onChange={onInputchange} />
            </div>
            <div>
                {filteredPosts < 1 ?
                (
                    <div>sorry not found.</div>
                )
                :
                (
                filteredPosts.map(post => {
                    return(
                    <div  key={post.id}>
                        <Link href={`/blog/${post.slug}`}><a > 
                            <Image src={post.image} alt={'some next picture'} width={500} height={500}/>
                        </a></Link>
                        <div>
                            <p>{post.title}</p>
                            <p>{post.postcontent.slice(0,200)}</p>

                            <p>
                            {post.form_field_options.author_name}

                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    )
                
                })
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default BlogHome
```

Im trying to fetch the nested JSON data. I tried using {post.form_field_options.author_name}. No error is thrown but the data doesn't show obviously I could not nest those values and call them directly but that would not be very DRY for what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: `form_field_options` is an array in your JSON data. To access the first item's `author_name` you should do `post.form_field_options[0].author_name`.

Comment: Also, to check the length of an array you should do `filteredPosts.length < 1`.

Comment: Awesome! makes perfect sense. Thanks.